# Why did Buddha praise the vedic Agnihotra as the foremost sacrifice?

Tags: hinduism, buddhist, vedas

Why Buddha praises the vedic Agnihotra as the foremost sacrifice and the Gayatri mantra as the foremost meter in the Pali Canon?

> aggihuttamukhā yaññā sāvittī chandaso mukham.
>
> Sacrifices have the agnihotra as foremost; of meter the foremost is
>   the Sāvitrī

["On the Buddha's Use of Some Brahmanical Motifs in Pali Texts"](http://jocbs.org/index.php/jocbs/article/view/76/96)

Comment: Your quote is not from theravāda-pali canon.

Comment: @Bonn Which quote?

Comment: Oṃ maṇi padme hūṃ

Comment: @Bonn when did I say it is from Theravada pali Canon? Are there any mantras in that Canon?

Comment: @Bonn You're interested only in Pali Canon? Okay then I will ask you. Why the Buddha praises the vedic Agnihotra as the foremost sacrifice and the Gayatri mantra as the foremost meter in Pali canon?

Comment: I answered below.

Comment: I think this is merely an attempt to find a Buddhist endorsement to Hindu rituals. You have to give up Hinduism if you want to practice Buddhism. This faith by endorsement thing won't work at all.

Answer (score 7):

Your quoted text is from [M.N. Selasutta](https://suttacentral.net/pi/mn92), that buddha taught to sela**brahmaṇa**:

> aggihuttamukhā yaññā sāvittī chandaso mukham.
>
> Sacrifices have the agnihotra as foremost; of meter the foremost is the Sāvitrī

So, buddha didn't taught veda. Buddha just use sela**brahmaṇa**'s knowledge, veda, to teach him the last line:

> puññaṃ ākaṅkhamānānaṃ, saṅgho ve yajataṃ mukha’’nti
>
> Saṅgha is the best foremost of wholesome-mind developers.

This last line is the real buddha's teaching. Your quoted line, veda, was used by buddha just as a simile, as a tool to make selabrahmmaṇa understand the last line.

Your quote is similar: it references an example of brahmaṇa-people's best thing, to show sela-brahmaṇa how the last line is the best. Only that last line is the buddha's teaching; your quote is just a borrowed example, which buddha borrowed from brahmaṇa's veda, to teach  sela-brahmaṇa the last line.

**How can you teach a new language to a foreigner? You use their already-known language to teach them new language, right? That is what buddha did.**

Comment: What's the connection with the last line and my Agnihotra quote?

Comment: Your quote is the similar example of brahmaṇa-people's best thing, to show sela-brahmaṇa that how the last line is the best. So, just that last line is the buddha's teaching, your quote is just a borrowed example that buddha borrowed from brahmaṇa's veda to teach  sela-brahmaṇa the last line.

Comment: Buddha has clearly praised  Vedic things except animal sacrifices. It's just that you're oblivious to it. You're reinterpreting what Buddha actually meant there.

Comment: No, no where in theravāda tipitaka-pāli and commentary-pāli looks like you said. I recite, memorize, and research tipitaka-pāli for many years. I never saw something like you said.  
When you use current government-made stuff, it doesn't mean you supporting or agree with this government.

Comment: Isn't samyutta nikaya part of pali Canon?

Comment: Your quoted text is the part of pāli, but the meaning of it doesn't mean buddha  praised Vedic things. It is just an example for comparison.

Comment: I don't know how Samyutta nikaya is classified? Samyutta Nikaya 111? What does this mean?

Comment: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/23846/can-someone-explain-the-difference-classification-and-referencing-between-englis

Comment: @OnkarKarambe Apparently the phrase is used in two or three suttas, including SN 111 and MN 92. Bonn referenced MN 92 (in Pali): [here is an English translation of MN 92](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/2Majjhima-Nikaya/Majjhima2/092-sela-e1.html) if you want to read the whole sutta. The connection is, the sutta says, "[Like] the fire sacrifice is the chief sacrifice ... the Communities of Bhikkhus is the chief to those desiring merit." If he'd been talking with a race-car driver instead of a brahman, he might instead have said "Like the Ferrari is the fastest car" oslt.

Comment: @OnkarKarambe The [Ajanna Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.013.than.html) is a good example. The Buddha first spoke about the nature and behaviour of an excellent breed of horse, and then used that as a simile to explain the nature and behaviour of an excellent monk. It doesn't mean that the Buddha is an expert on horses, or is giving advice about horses. The Parable of the Poison Arrow and the Parable of Simsapa Leaves are more examples of Buddha's use of similes and metaphors. The house builder in the Dhammapada is another good metaphor.