# Can someone explain the difference classification and referencing between english tipitaka and thai tipitaka?

Tags: pali-canon

It is very hard for me to find english translation tipitaka online, because it's classification look like very difference from thai and burma tipitaka.

Also, english translation tipitaka online have not all tipitaka part. Many part of pāli canon looks lost from english translation.

Comment: Is this question is a duplicate of (already answered by) the topic [Tripitaka Section Numbering](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3770/254)?

Comment: Thank you. Should I delete this question?

Comment: It's isn't necessary to delete it. SE suggest that this kind of closed-but-not-deleted topic can be a useful signpost to future readers. If you searched for something and didn't find it before you asked this question, the next person who does the same search as you did will find this question (and thus be directed towards the topic which answers it).